# How to select only first and last element from an array without aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to retrieve only the first and last element from an array in a document, by using the "find" function, without using "aggregate".

[Here is a Mongo Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nX9U6LfiXDo)

Consider a document

```
{
    _id:"1",
    messages:[
        {
            "text":"First item",
        },
        {
            "text":"Middle item",
        },
        {
            "text":"Last item",
        },
    ],
}
```

So far, I was able to retrieve only the first or last, for example, to get the last item, I am doing:

```
messages: {
    $slice: ["$messages", -1], //Get the last element
},
```

How can I get both the first (0th index) and the last (nth index) at the same time?

Note: I do not have any information about the length of the array from beforehand.

Note 2: The reason why I would prefer not using "aggregate" is due to having more filters, selections, limits and other various query properties being handled through the find(), limit(), etc. functions of mongoose, which I am using in a generic way to define my wrapper.

Comment: I can't think of a way without aggregation... What are your other filters? Maybe you can migrate them all to aggregation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want both values, list them both with a projection like:

```
{
  messages: [
    {$slice: ["$messages", 1]},
    {$slice: ["$messages",-1],}
  ],
}
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using aggregate you can use [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/) and [$last](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last-array-element/) like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "first": {
        "$first": "$messages"
      },
      "last": {
        "$last": "$messages"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b_QlF5pQ9tV)

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do it by normal find method? I am using various other filters, selections and etc. And in that case it'll be great if I can just modify part of the "select" area, like I am doing in my example playground.